# How to validate legacy coordinate pairs with custom validator in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use the following schema definition with custom valication:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({

});

Schema.add({
    location: {
       type: [Number] /*[<longitude>, <latitude>]*/,
       index: '2d',
       validate: function (location) {
          // do cheching here
       }
    }
});
```

What is the best way to check that format location of is correct (legacy coordinate pairs) and return formatted error in opposite case?